# has_many through association sql error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, sqlite, rspec-rails

So, I'm trying to test my models associations with the following test:

```rb
it 'retrieve items registered under person' do
  p = FactoryGirl.create(:person)
  o = FactoryGirl.create(:order, customer: p)
  o.customer.should == p
  i = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
  o.items << i
  o.save
  p.items.count.should == 1
end
```

My models:

```rb
class Person < AR:Base
  has_many :orders, :as => :customer
  has_many :items, :through => :orders
end

class Order < AR:Base
  has_many :items
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => Person
end

class Item < AR:Base
  belongs_to :order
  has_one :customer, :class_name => Person, :through => :order
end
```

But when I run the test it gives me the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: orders.customer_type: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "items" INNER JOIN "orders" ON "items"."order_id" = "orders"."id" WHERE "orders"."customer_id" = 1 AND "orders"."customer_type" = 'Person'
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
The problem was on the ':as => :customer' bit. But my real problem was with the test. I should have assigned an order in the creation of an item.

Comment: no column customer_type in orders table probably.

Comment: Yeah, that I got.
But why is it looking for a column customer_type?

Comment: Are you sure these models don't use single table inheritance? Because that would cause ActiveRecord to look up a `model_type`.

Comment: Can you post your db/schema.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `:as` option specifies a polymorphic interface. This explains  `"orders"."customer_type" = 'Person'` in the where clause. I think what you mean to do is:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders, :foreign_key => :customer_id
  has_many :items, :through => :orders
end
```

See the `:as` option in the [guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many).

Comment: so true, :as indeed is used in polymorphic associations.

Answer (score 0):

I think Item should belong_to customer through order

```
class Item < AR:Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :customer, :class_name => Person, :through => :order
end
```